# LINQ select when not EndsWith in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is this possible to LINQ query all elements except those meeting criteria EndsWith(String), essentially all which NOT EndsWith(String)?

For example this code selects all items where last Uri segment ends with ".txt", but I would like to select all except those which end with ".txt":

`ListBlobs(BlobPrefix).Where(Function(item) item.Uri.Segments.Last().EndsWith(".txt")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already have your answer there:

> all which **NOT** EndsWith(String)?

Since `.EndsWith()` returns a Boolean, simply use a `Not` operator.

`ListBlobs(BlobPrefix).Where(Function(item) Not item.Uri.Segments.Last().EndsWith(".txt")`